# get elasticsearch schema via commandline tool

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get up to speed on an elasticsearch implementation on a project. How can I see the data that is on the cluster? Is there a commandline tool that gives me information on the schema?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get schema:

```
curl -XGET 'http://loadtest-appserver1:9200/myIndex/_mapping'
```

See [Elasticsearch Api Doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/)

Comment: Is it just me or are there too many Q's here that can be found by a quick read of the docs... Are they really that bad!

Comment: The documentation is pretty poor. How can I install elasticsearch-head without being a mac user in a startup? I dont have things like `npm install` or `grunt server` on a restricted remote GNU/Linux server in my bureaucratic technology infrastructure.

Comment: I agree that the documentation is poor and badly structured in a lot of areas. The API documentation is quite good though.

Comment: would you be able to help with the question about running a frontend monitoring tool for elasticsearch in my restricted linux environment? Ideally i would like to untar a distribution and run some built-in webui server to expose the elasticsearch monitoring on a port so that i can navigate to the URL and see whats going on in the engine

Comment: add `?pretty=1` if you want it formatted in a human readable form

Answer (score 1):

Try using ElasticSearch Head

http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/

It's a great tool when peeking in your index and it's meta data (such as the schema) to find out what's going on.

Also it's HTML5/REST based, so you can take a look in your browser at the commands it sends to your cluster and use those with command line CURL if needed.